# how to create in unity fps game fps camera 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to create fps game where player can move w a s d and jump with spacebar but also mouse in center of game and i can rotate camera when i move my camera also need i check freeze rotation
*All game is 3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 1.5f;
    
        public Transform head;
    
        public float sensitivity = 5f; 
        public float headMinY = -40f; 
        public float headMaxY = 40f;
    
        public KeyCode jumpButton = KeyCode.Space; 
        public float jumpForce = 10; 
        public float jumpDistance = 1.2f; 
    
        private Vector3 direction;
        private float h, v;
        private int layerMask;
        private Rigidbody body;
        private float rotationY;
    
        void Start()
        {
            body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            body.freezeRotation = true;
            layerMask = 1 << gameObject.layer | 1 << 2;
            layerMask = ~layerMask;
        }
    
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            body.AddForce(direction * speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    
            // Ограничение скорости, иначе объект будет постоянно ускоряться
            if (Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed)
            {
                body.velocity = new Vector3(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed, body.velocity.y, body.velocity.z);
            }
            if (Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.z) > speed)
            {
                body.velocity = new Vector3(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.y, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.z) * speed);
            }
        }
    
        bool GetJump() 
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, jumpDistance, layerMask))
            {
                return true;
            }
    
            return false;
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
            float rotationX = head.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, headMinY, headMaxY);
            head.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    
        
            direction = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
            direction = head.TransformDirection(direction);
            direction = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z);
    
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpButton) && GetJump())
            {
                body.velocity = new Vector2(0, jumpForce);
            }
        }
    
        void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * jumpDistance);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems mostly correct. However, you need to replace the `fixUpdate` with `update` for smoother input handling since update since it is called once per frame and its execution.
Second you need to change the `body.velocity` assignment in the GetJump() method should be changed to `body.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);`

see if that works